# Problem using Python to slice lists to map data

Tags: python, slice

One of my new duties requires me to translate or map data from one format to another, usually from xcel, csv or ms mdb into xml, sql or per a spec that I am given so usually each mapping is different. I have taken to learning Python to do this as a precursor to Lisp. I am learning more each day and am actually having fun at my job. I am curently trying to wrap my brain around Generators and Iterators but am not sure yet as to when how they are needed but here is where I am stuck.

What is the proper pythonic way to use a value from within a slice to test for certain conditions and if met then assign the appropriate value. When I try to an if elif with <= I am not getting the result that I want. The example below is just one of many if elif statements I created to test for conditions.

```
#This works
hsa_id = ''
if "1" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '<4 hours'
elif "2" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '<4 hours'
elif "4" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '4-8 hours'
elif "5" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '4-8 hours'
elif "6" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '4-8 hours'
elif "8" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '8-16 hours'
elif "9" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '8-16 hours'
elif "16" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '16-24 hours'
elif "17" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '16-24 hours'
elif "24" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '16-24 hours'
elif "25" in csvitem[63:64]:
    hsa_id = '>24 hours'
else:
    hsa_id = ''
HOURSSINCEAWAKENING.append(hsa_id)

#This does not work. I tried removing the quotes. With and without the quotes I get all identical values.
hsa_id = ''
    if csvitem[63:64] <= "3":
        hsa_id = '<4 hours'
    elif csvitem[63:64] <= "7":
        hsa_id = '4-8 hours'
    elif csvitem[63:64] <= "15":
        hsa_id = '8-16 hours'
    elif csvitem[63:64] <= "23":
        hsa_id = '16-24 hours'
    elif csvitem[63:64] > "23":
        hsa_id = '>24 hours'
    else:
        hsa_id = ''
    HOURSSINCEAWAKENING.append(hsa_id)  

#Output from what does not work truncated for brevity as there are thousands of records.
['<4 hours', '<4 hours', '<4 hours', '<4 hours',...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings and probably you want to compare numbers. Use int()

```
if int(csvitem[63]) <= 3:
```

Probably you also want to refactorize your code to eliminate so many if's. As an example you could do something like:

```
data = [(3, '<4'), (7, '4-8'), (15, '8-16'), (23, '16-24'), (10000, '>24']

dattime = int(cvsitem[63])
hsa_id = ''
for mytime, text in data:
    if dattime <= mytime:
        hsa_id = '%s hours' % text
        break
```

And the same can be done for the first chain of if's in your code. In this case, however, it would be better to build a dict with your options and then to use it as:

```
choices_dict = {'1':'<4 hours', ...}
hsa_id = choices_dict.get(cvsitem[63], '')
```

Comment: I did originally try that but since that slice is a list I am not able to cast the item into an integer for testing. I get the following error:   if int(csvitem[63:64]) <= 3:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: the list has only one char, try int(cvsitem[63:64][0])

Comment: in  any case you can simplify with cvsitem[63] and you will get directly the number and not a list with a number.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings. Look at that comparisions:

```
>>> "23"<"3"
True
>>> "04"<"3"
True
```

I think you want to compare the integer values. Try this:
...
    if int(csvitem[63:64]) <= 3:
...
etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you tell python to compare things, it will very rarely complain. If you tell it to compare a string with a banana, it will probably tell you one is bigger than the other, but the answer will hold no sense to you.

You are comparing strings with numbers. You should compare numbers against numbers:

```
>>> "3" < "20"
False
>>> "3" < "20"
False
>>> int("3") < int("20")
True
```

Turn your strings into numbers before comparing, and you'll be fine.

Comment: is there a way that I can do that when I create my list after reading in the csv? I am reading in my csv with: `try:
    rlist = list(csv.reader(rh))`
`except csv.Error as e:`
    `sys.exit("file %s, line %d: %s" % (filename, reader.line_num, e))`
`finally:`
    `rh.close()`  Then I am enumeraing my list with the following:  `mList = enumerate(rlist)`      
    `for i, csvitem in mList:` and then from here I am testing the slices that contain data that needs to be converted or mapped into its new meaning.

Comment: @MWR the best approach, I think, is to create a class that reflects the content of a row in the csv. In the __init__ method, take the slices you need, convert them to integers (or whatever) when necessary, and then (if you want) provide accessor properties for the object's members. This will decouple the CSV format from the rest of your program, since you'll be handling your own objects, and should the format change, or the data arrive through a different interface, the rest of your logic will be safely unchanged. It will also perform the necessary type conversions out of your sight, of course

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- Your slice contains a single character, but you're comparing 2.
- You're doing relational string comparisons instead of integer comparisons.
- Python has a module for dealing with CSV data so you don't need to slice at all.
- You should be using a dict to hold the values you want to compare instead of having a large if/elif structure.

Comment: I do not understand where I am comparing 2? I thought by saying if csvitem[63:64] <= "3": then do something. I basically want python to take whatever value is at the slice csvitem[63:64] and compare it to a value and if true set the variable to a desired value. I did not use a dict in this case because I must maintain the order and I am using python 2.6 which as I understand it does not have an ordered dict like py3.1+ does.

Comment: `elif csvitem[63:64] <= "23":` compares 1 against 2. And you'd use the dict to store the comparison values, not the results.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is csvitem in your example?  From your example (and the name), I'm assuming it's a sequence of items of some kind.  Eg ["a","b", "c" .... "25", ...].

However, in this case, taking a slice and using `in` is a bit roundabout - it's extracting a list of a single element (eg ["25"] and checking membership.  Instead, you should really do something like `if '25' == csvitem[63].

Your other problem is because the datatype of the item is a string, which will compare differently to numbers.  To treat the item as a number, convert it to one first, with the `int` function.  Eg:

```
if int(csvitem[63]) <= 3:
    hsa_id = '<4 hours'
```

Also, it might be worth noting a useful feature of python here: that of operator chaining.  Unlike many languages, you can check for a range of values using the syntax "`lowerbound < value < upper_bound`" (using the appropriate comparison).  You could write your example as:

```
hours = int(csvitem[63])
if hours < 4:
    hsa_id = "<4 hours"
elif 4 <= hours < 8:
    hsa_id = "4-8 hours"
elif 8 <= hours < 16:
    hsa_id = "8-16 hours"
elif 16 <= hours <= 24:
    hsa_id = "16-24 hours"
else:
    hsa_id = ">24 hours"
```

Comment: You are exactly correct, I am taking a single item from each record of thousands and based on some condition I want the old value to be mapped to or converted to a new value. In this case I have a field in each record that denotes the amount of hours awake and I want to test that value and map it to the new criteria. So for all records where the value is 0 to 3 I want all those values changed to '< 4 hours'. I am aware of chaining but I have not been able figure out how to cast slice items into an int because fwiw each of the items in the list are sublists if that makes any sense.

Comment: The issue is that a slice of a list is always a list.  When you're extracting a single element, don't use a slice at all, use an index directly (ie. csvitem[63] rather tha  csvitem[63:64]).  Alternatively, if you've got the slice already, get the first (single) element in it with theSlice[0]